# Webserver over Internet not just localhost

Tags: vb.net

I have made a "webserver" in vb.net the problem is that it seems like it's just listening to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and not request that is sent over the internet. I have changed the listening adress to my public internet ip but it's still just listening to local requests.

Do someone have a source code with a working example of how this could be accomplished?

```
Dim address As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(79.138.xxx.xxx)
Dim EndPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(address,8082)

Dim ss As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
ss.Bind(EndPoint)
ss.Listen(20)
```

Comment: How can you be sure that the request reaches your server from your public ip? You are probably behind NAT. More information required on what you have changed etc.

Comment: The weird thing is that I have an apache server that runs on the same computer (diffrent port). And that works just perfect over internet. So that's why I assumed that my request to my vb.net webserver would reach my computer without any problem. Is their something else that I'm missing? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: post your "webserver" code, only way to tell :)

Comment: Okey will do :) I have updated my original post with the code that probably is the problem.

Comment: If you turn off the Apache server, and use its port in your code, is that successful?

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind any kind of network?  This includes a router from your ISP, or generally any hardware other than the simplest of modems.

Easy way to tell would be to do an IPCONFIG and see what your local IP address is set to.  To do so, open a command prompt, and enter:  **ipconfig /all**

My output, as an example, is this:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-FB-8A-59-8E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2 (Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, December 27, 2010 7:50:12 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 28, 2010 9:13:01 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                       68.238.0.12
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

This tell me that the IP address of my computer is 192.168.1.2, which is far different than that of my public internet connection, due to being behind a router.

If this is the case, you'll need to open a path from the public world to your specific IP address behind your hardware.  This is usually referred to as Port Forwarding or similar, and would be configured in your router/firewall.

Also, as a doublecheck, do you have software firewalls disabled?

Comment: My computer is connected directly to my isp without any router. So no port forwarding is required on my side. I also don't have any firewall installed so that can't be a problem. I believe the problem is somewhere in my code.

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : alltele.opennet.se
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 79.138.xxx.xxx
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.128
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 79.138.xxx.xxx